# Library for fast semistructured data serialization in Python

Tags: python, json, performance, serialization, avro

What would be the canonical way to save precomputed, semi-structured data such that it can be deserialized as fast as possible?

There is [orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson#performance), which is a very-performant json serialization. But JSON is not a proper choice compared to binary-encoded formats.

For Avro, there is [fastavro](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro), although they do not have any benchmarks to prove their performance.

What would be the canonical choice for maximal throughput during deserialization?